# Equation for a systematic permutation

Tags: combinations, permutations

A $6$ digit number is set whereby every digit can be repeated without any constraints. So one can have a number between $000001$ and $999999$. (Zeros on the left are counted).

**The problem:**
Generate all possible patterns by translating the numbers into characters.

**The constraints:**
- Letters used are only $a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ e,$ and $f$.

So the pattern can range between $aaaaaa$ and $abcdef$.

- Characters should run systematic order
- The first character is always "$a$"

So the number $454657$ is translated to $abacbd$ or $123456$ is translated to $abcdef$. ($c$ Can't exist if there is no $b$ and $d$ can't exist if there is no $b$ and $c$)
What do we call these types of permutations? How is it calculated? How can I get the equation?  Please help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how your translation works. Would the number $454653$ translate to $bcbdca$ or $abacbd$?

Comment: Also, are you asking for the number of distinct strings of letters you can get from these types of "translations"?

Comment: $454653$ would translate to $abacbd$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee yes, I'd like to know how i can reach the number of distinct strings and the name of this specific function in order to be able to generate all possible scenarios.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee also, **f** is always the $6th$ character and can only exist if the if all 6 digits are different from one another. Example: $123456 = abcdef$ or $ 874321 = abcdef$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let S(n, r) be the number of patterns with n characters and r distinct characters.
We wish to find a explicit formula for sum of all S(n,r) for given n and varying r. 
Let this sum be B(n).

We first construct the recurrence relation:

S(n, r) = S(n-1, r-1) + rS(n-1, r).

This is because for a pattern with n characters and r distinct characters we can consider if the last character was distinct from all the rest or not, giving rise to the two cases.

With the equation, we note that this is exactly the recurrence relation (with same boundary conditions) as Stirling numbers of the second kind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

and that the sum S(n) is given by the Bell numbers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Going back to the question, the answer would be B(6) = 203 (the 7th Bell number)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much :)